# bash command with regular expressions won't move files

Tags: find

I have multiple files in this directory `someDir` and I'm trying to move only the ones that have this ending `O_010_0000000028181996.xml`

I've checked my regular expression online and it matches,the problem is when I run my bash command the files do not get moved to the folder `found`.

My command bash command is

```
find /home/someDir/ -regex '\d{10}.{3}O_010_0000000028181996\.xml' -exec mv '{}' /home/found/ \;
```

Example of filenames in directory someDir:

```
0208420319-1-O_010_0000000028174248.xml
0208461630-1-O_010_0000000028178356.xml
0208696934-1-O_010_0000000028181996.xml
0208696935-1-O_010_0000000028181996.xml
0208735127-1-O_010_0000000028186468.xml
0208774443-1-O_010_0000000028191308.xml
0208812611-1-O_010_0000000028196104.xml
0208858156-1-O_010_0000000028198984.xml
```

Comment: You match against the full path with `-regex`, not just the filename.  Also, this has _nothing_ to do with `bash`, and everything to do with GNU `find`.

Comment: The regex needs to match the entire path that `find` sees, including the path you set as argument `-regex '/home/someDir/\d{10}.{3}O_010_0000000028181996\.xml'` or similar depending on whether there are subdirectories

Comment: @muru OK, please explain then why this command gets executed then ```find /home/someDir/ -regex '.*\.xml' -exec mv '{}' /home/found/ \;```

Comment: `.*` covers the path.

Comment: I've tryed with path but it does not work```find /home/someDir/ -regex '/home/someDir/\d{10}.{3}O_010_0000000028181996\.xml' -exec mv '{}' /home/found/ \;```

Comment: What `find` implementation are you using? At least with GNU find, AFAIK none of the built-in regextypes supports the PCRE `\d` for a decimal digit. Probably the closest you'll get is `-regextype egrep -regex '.*/[0-9]{10}.{3}O_010_0000000028181996\.xml'`

Comment: @steeldriver it worked! please aswer the question I have to award you.

Comment: @CristianMateica done - please see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least with GNU `find`, you can see what regular expression flavors it supports using

```
$ find -regextype help
find: Unknown regular expression type ‘help’; valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’.
```

AFAIK none of these supports the PCRE `\d` for a decimal digit. Additionally, the `findutils-default` type that applies when no explicit `-regextype` is given only supports `*`, `+`, and `?` as quantifiers.

Probably the closest you will get is to replace `\d` by `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` and use `-regextype egrep` or `-regextype posix-extended` ex.

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[0-9]{10}.{3}O_010_0000000028181996\.xml'
```

See also

- [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)